# How to have my contents resize along with the browser window?

Tags: css

I can't figure out how to keep my contents in ratio with the browser. they keep their size and gets moved around when i resize the browser window. I'm new to php/css btw.

I've tried max/min width but on my container div but it doesn't seem to work.
I may have added a few more properties that i don't need on my css, please feel free to correct me if in case some are redundant or missing.

```css
       body{
         margin:0;
         padding:0;
         overflow-x:hidden;
         height: 100%;
         
        }
        #container{
         width: auto;
         height: 720px;
         margin: 0 auto;
         position: absolute !important;
         display: block;
         text-align: left;
         font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
         font-size: 13px;
        }
        #header{
         height:auto;
         
        }
        #navBar{
         height:45px;
         overflow:-x:hidden;

        }
        #marquee{
         height: 32px;
         background-color: #b71c1c;
         font-size:24px;
         color: #ffffff;
         font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
         marquee-speed: fast;
         padding-left: 11px;
         padding-right: 11px;
         margin: 0px auto;

        }
        #content{
         height:auto;
         width: 60%;
            padding: 0 20px 0 20px; 
         display: inline-block;

        }
        #h1{
         font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
         font-size:24px;
        
         font-weight:bold;
         padding-top:4px;
         padding-right:0px;
         padding-left:3px;
         padding-bottom:8px;
         display:inline-block;
        }
        #h1 img {
         vertical-align: middle;
         display:inline-block;
        /* margin-left:40%;*/
        }

        #footer{
         font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
         font-size:14px;
         width:auto;
            height: 140px;
         color:#FFF;
         padding-top: 30px;
         padding-bottom: 30px;
         padding-left:110px;
         padding-right:110px;
            background-color: #000;
            z-index: 3000;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
        /*    position: fixed;*/
            clear: both;
        }
        #leftNav { 
         height: 100%;
            float: left; 
            width: 16%; 
            background: #f5f5f5; 
            padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px;
         
        }
        #rightNav { 
         height: 100%;
            float: right; 
            width: 16%; 
            background: #f5f5f5; 
            padding: 10px 10px 13px 5px;
         display:block; 
        }
        #adContainer{
         display:block;
         margin: 0 0 0 0px; 
            padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
        }
        #images {
         width:auto;
         margin: 0 0 0 0px; 
            padding: 10px 20px 10px 0px;
        }
        
        #videoPlayer {
         width:35%;
         height:auto;
         margin:0 auto;
         position:relative;
         display:block; 
         padding-bottom: 15px; 
        }
```

```html
 <div id="container">
            <div id="navBar">            
             <nav>
                <a href="#"><img src="assets/test.png"</a>
           <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a>
            <li><a href="#">Properties</a>
            <li><a href="#">Locations</a>
                        <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
            <li><a href="contactUs.php">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
           </ul>
          </nav>
         </div>
            <div id="header">
        <div id="wowslider-container1">
        </div>
        <div id="marquee"><marquee>*** #######  ***</marquee></div>
        <div id="leftNav">
            <leftNav>
          <ul>
           <li><a href="">Quick Links</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Locations</a></li>
                     <ul>
                         <li><a href="test1.php"><img src="assets/test Settings.jpg" height="50" width="50"  /> test test</a></li>
                         <li><a href="test2.php">Avida Cloverfield</a></li>
                        </ul>
          </ul>
              </leftNav>
        </div>
        <div id="rightNav">
            <div id="adContainer">your ads
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
          
          <br />
          
          <h1 align="left"><img src="assets/prop.jpg" width="462" height="288" alt="Prop" /><br /><strong>test</h1>
          <p align="left">test</p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
          <p>Footer info</p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What part of your CSS do you think *should* account for the resizing of contents along with the browser window? Also, [`marquee`, really](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee)?

Comment: shouldn't it be the container? since all of the contents are within it?

Comment: Remove `position: absolute` from `#container`. This is causing the width to collapse. I cant think of a sensible reason why you would want to absolutely position the container.

Comment: I just noticed my layout does resize, but the text and images doesn't.

Comment: Thanks @Turnip, I was just checking if it would have any effects.

Comment: Rye, you want to look into media queries and relative (font) size units like `em` and `rem`.